# Find a 4 × 4 matrix A =[a ij ] whose entries satisfy the stated condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

> Find a $4\times4$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ whose entries satisfy the stated condition.
>
> (a) $a_{ij}=i+j$
>   (b) $a_{ij}=i^{j-1}$
>   (c) $a_{ij}=
> \begin{cases} 
> 1,&\text{if }|i-j|>1\\
> -1,&\text{if }|i-j|\le1
> \end{cases}$

I gotta admit it guys, I'm completely lost as heck on this one... don't know where to begin

Comment: In (a), what is $a_{11}$, can you tell?

Comment: Very good. So out of the sixteen possible entries in $A$, you got one down. Can you find the others?

Comment: oh so this is 3 different matrices i have to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for (a) we have $a_{ij}=i+j$ so compute this, for instance $a_{11}=1+1=2,a_{3,4}=3+4=7$, it would be labourios to write all of this out.

(b) take for example $a_{1,2}=1^{2-1}=1$.

(c) This is the only example that has nice structure.if $|i-j|\le 1$ corresponds to the diagonal entries, and the first off diagonal entries i.e. $a_{1,2},a_{2,1}$ etc, but not $a_{22}$,  $|i-j|\gt 1$ just corresponds to the remaining entries.